# Disable touch panning for body of site on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, html, css, view, meta

The site I am working on www.salonbkb.com when in a mobile browser will act responsive but will allow the user to use touch to move the site from left to right creating a whitespace on the remaining space after the drag.

Foundation.zurb.com does not do this nor do most sites I have found.  I believe msn.com still does this.

How can I prevent this from happening.

I tried

```
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no"/>
```

but that didn't do anything.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A page will not do this ordinarily if you have `width=device-width, initial-scale=1`.  Some element is stretching the page, allowing the user to pan sideways.  This will often happen if you have margins on a 100% width element, or if `box-sizing` is not set to `border-box` and there is padding on the 100% width element.  You just need to find the element (chrome devtools is useful for this, keep scrolling down and try to find the one with a big border that sticks out) and modify or remove it.

By the way, I would highly recommend against setting `user-scalable=no` or `maximum-scale=1`.  It's terrible for usability.  Users should be able to zoom in.  There are almost no good use cases for this.  If you're concerned about tap delay, use [fastclick](https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick).

Comment: You are awesome thanks... took forever to find.  one thing that I would add to your explanation is that it is not only for width of 100% and an extra margin I believe that it is also if the width plus an applied margin is outside of the size of the screen/viewport.  It wasn't the width of 100% it was a width of 295 + a sum total of left /right margin of about 60px... << does that sound correct?  because this is what took me so long to find the mistake.

Comment: Yes, that sounds like a problem and a reason to avoid using pixel sizes in responsive design :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript to disable the default actions of the browser (like page drag).

```
document.addEventListener("touchmove",function(event){event.preventDefault();});
```

BUT, that will stop the user from being able to scroll down also. to prevent only sideways you would have to add conditions that check the touch direction...

```
 document.addEventListener("touchmove",function(event){
      if(//check if the absolute value
           of last touch.x -current touch.x 
           is greater than some threshhold){

            event.preventDefault();
       }
  });
```

Comment: That isn't going to work, it will allow diagonal drags.  And it's the worst way to do it.  You can force the body to avoid scrolling sideways by setting overflow-x: none.... so why bother with the JS?

Comment: this stopped the page from moving around for me.