# Disabling pan out of mobile site

Tags: html, css, mobile, responsive-design

I am having some trouble. When I look at my site on a mobile browsers it lets me pan out creating white space. I saw a similar question asked but the answer doesnt seem to match up with my problem.

[Disable touch panning for body of site on mobile devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25099517/disable-touch-panning-for-body-of-site-on-mobile-devices)

there is the question and the answer states the it must be a margin set to 100% i dont have any thing set to 100% except for

```
       body, html {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

and 
     `background-size: cover;`
Could either of those be the culprit?

Answer (score 0):

That actually sounds like you may not have your viewport meta tag set correctly. There are a few variants based on whether you want users to be able to zoom or not. Take a look at the options here. It's a blog post (full disclosure, it's one of mine) that explains them. http://benfrain.com/understanding-the-viewport-meta-tag-and-css-viewport/

Comment: my viewport tag is     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> which i believe is correct right? I'll check out the article though thanks.

Comment: No, that sounds right. You have a url you can share?

Comment: yes. gabrielwebb.github.io is the actual site and the css is here http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LEZJMG. Not sure which would help more.